# POST method in powershell gives 405 error

Tags: powershell, postman, amazon-cognito

I have a POST method that works fine in Postman but I can't get it working in powershell.
The client id and client secret are setup in AWS cognito.
I am using basic authentication to retrieve the access token.
Below is my code,

```
$encodedlogin="MNBvbmZfYWsxUTRocG1qOG5zOGZqZ8xvN646a1plMDNsMTZjY6xucTA5MzVkOGg2aGdlaG1mdXAxaHZkMmlxaXY0PKOdM3BcxNBtPLs5"
        
$authorisation = "Basic " + $encodedlogin
        
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
        
$headers.Add("Authorization",$authorisation)    
$headers.Add("Accept","application/json")
$headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json")
$headers.Add("ResponseType","id_token")
        
$body = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$body.Add("grant_type","client_credentials")
$body.Add("scope","cybergate-gateway-resources/cybertron.fullaccess")
        
$uri = "https://cybergate.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token"
        
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -body $body -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"
```

The error as follows,

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
At C:\CyberGate\src\CyberGate.API\Scripts\Deploy\CyberGate.ps1:33 char:17
+ ... $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -body $body ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your postman request? Best to export it as `curl`.

Comment: Shouldn't the body be in JSON format?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have resolved the issue by changing the -ContentType from "application/json" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". As follows, $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -body $body -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"